# Load tags into input field from PHP array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tags

This tag system at below is very suitable for me:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Wky2Z/11/**

I want add some function to this tagging system. Firstly, before making tag I want to load tags while typing into box. For example, I have PHP array like below:

```
$tags = array(1 =>'hello', 'hi', 'name', 'surname');
```

So, if the text inside box is suitable one of the tag in array, then we can make a tag, while pressing Enter...In my opinion it would be better do it via Ajax, because all tags will be able to be in database...

I have tried to do it by myself, searched google, but did not find that what I need actually.

P.S IF you do not understand this question: remember tagging system of stackoverflow....

Comment: Are you suggesting autocomplete?

Comment: Yes..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NYV5T/

allowed tags are cheese, potato and pickle (anything in the allowedTags array)

```
tags = [];
allowedTags = ["cheese","potato", "pickle"];
$("#textBox").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        if (allowedTags.indexOf(this.value) !== -1){
            $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag' >"  + this.value+'<span class="cross">X</span>'+ "</a>");


        tags.push(this.value);
        this.value = "";

        }else{
            alert("not allowed tag");
        }

    }
});

$('body').on('click','.cross',function(){

    tags.splice($(this).parent('a').html(), 1);
    $(this).parent('a').remove();
});

$( "#textBox" ).autocomplete({
  source: allowedTags
});
```

The key part of this is the if statement 'allowedTags.indexOf' will return -1 if there is no matching tag in 'allowedTags'.

All you then need to do is populate the allowed tags from your database - you could do this via an ajax call or (if your list is less than 100 tags) I would say it is more efficient to populate the array at page load once.

As per OP request have added auto-complete to make this a complete solution.

NOTE!!! - This is assuming you have jquery-ui included

Comment: That is absouletely nice, but it would be better show tags while typing. F.e if I type c, i want display the tag cheese at below, or if i type p, show potato